Manager wrecking my time off
I'm on an expensive vacation and my project manager wrecked 2 of 3 vacation days by trying to "fix" issues without me. I spent the night before the main event debugging, until 3am.
This guy seems unable to listen to my technical recommendations (in this situation he did the exact thing I told him not to do). Then bad things happen and I have to work overtime to fix the disaster. I take my work seriously but it's not the first time he's ruined my days off, and it needs to stop.
I talked with other devs and apparently I'm not the only one who has had such issues with him. How to get him to respect my time? Should I just let him crash and burn, if he gets himself into trouble?

Why are you working on your vacation?

Because I tried ignoring project manager, then my people manager called (he's dev so if he calls then it's actually serious, not like prod manager team, which calls for nonsense I'm not gonna fix on vacation) and told me that the minor problem which was there is now a major problem. And I don't want customer to think product is trash...which it is trash, they hired somebody awful to build it which is not my fault, but awful somebody left after end of contract and I don't want it to look like I build trash.

It doesn’t look like you respect your time. Why do you expect them to do it? Have you reflected with them about these situations? Is the fixing something you do on the side, or are you actually getting paid/compensated for it?

You need to go on holiday. End of.

Even if you don't take the advice of all the other posts saying "don't do anything like work while you are on vacation", if your boss says "I did some fixes and now they have broken stuff" should be "Just roll back everything you did and we will fix it when I get back".

Now you have learned a valuable lesson in telling your Boss that your holiday will be in the middle of nowhere with no cell phone reception or internet access. Then turn your phone off. Problem solved.

@chladnefazole You are asking a reasonable question. But I suggest in my answer that you might consider "is this company good for my career growth?" as your question.

Let it burn baby.  The same old adage, if you die they will fill your position before the obituary is written.  They are willing to burn your vacation, you should not care if their business burns while you are away..

@chladnefazole I updated my answer to explain why the problem is more than being bothered during vacation. It really is much worse than that.

Why would you even answer the phone if you see its him while on leave?

@DJClayworth +1, and the order of priority for rolling back (or fixing if not possible) should be (i) Bob (ii) whoever gave PM Bob permission to push broken code to production (iii) whoever devised the policy that Bob didn't need explicit permission to push without thoroughly testing everything and getting reviews (iv) whoever let this project get to a bus factor of 1.   It's bad enough that PMs and the like can dump their failures on devs at the best of times, but dumping them on a dev on holiday shows all sense of boundaries is gone at this company.

Before you go on holiday, do whatever handover needs doing, and make it clear that you're going to be off for the next week (or whatever) and uncontactable.
Then you take your holiday somewhere that doesn't have phone reception/accessible Internet and switch off for a few weeks. Or at least, you do that as far as your company is concerned.
Since you've shown that you're willing to answer work calls and stay up working until 3AM while you're on holiday then they're going to keep expecting you to do so. You need to put your foot down or you're never going to be able to take proper time off.

This makes sense for a "normal" company. This company is foo bar, based on the described past and current behaviors. Hand-off won't help for a manager / company that just doesn't "get it".

@DogBoy37 Yes it will, or at least might. The manager is now facing the consequences of screwing up. Higher managers will ask questions. At least sometimes the manager will need to change. Nothing in the question indicates that this is a wider problem with the company, just this particular manager.

@DJClayworth I strongly believe that this a company is the problem. Issue occured more than once. But the fact that a manager is either allowed to or been encouraged to not be risk adverse is dangerous. I say encouraged because that type of poor thinking being tolerated is encouragement. Change management? Hell with it! Roll backs? Hell with it! SLA? Who cares! Customers? Screw them! Employees? Screw them twice! That is this company's thinking when they allow this behavior a second time. No ifs ands or buts. I am not one to say leave a job. In this case, I suggest to run.

@DogBoy37 I think you are jumping to a conclusion. I've been in companies with bad managers who were tolerated for a while, usually to give them a chance to change, just like we would expect any employee to be given a chance to change their ways before being fired. A good company will sort it out, but it can take time.

@DJClayworth Normally I would agree with you. I am very slow to call a company horrible. At my company, we've made our share of mistakes over the years. One can learn more from failures than successes (IMHO). The culture where needless risk is ignored multiple times is a major red flag. If it happened once - fine. More than once AND clients were affected AND no plan "B" even considered AND no lessons learned from the last time. That adds up to more than a lone wolf bad manager. That is why in this case I am so harsh. They tolerate it / approve of it. If they won't learn, why stay?

You talk to his boss, that's how.  And talk to your boss about what Bob is doing to make your life hard.
"Bob did exactly what I told him not to, and as a result, I've spent 8 hours of my vacation fixing his screw-ups.  I need you to fix Bob."
I'm not going to tell you to let him crash and burn because that would probably take the project with it, and it's never good to be associated with a failed project.

Awesome, I will definitely do that, thanks.

One educational method is going to HR, demanding that these two days are added back to you holiday allowance, and send an expense report for the portion of your holiday where you had to work. If some small underling in HR refuses go up the chain, until you tell the head of HR that the pay or the cost of your lawyer will get added.

This only makes sense if you can actually get them to pay for it, which sounds unlikely. Their likely defense is going to be "you should've just said no, then!" and it'll probably hold.

@Erik It's plausible that they'd refuse to pay for expenses, but would be willing to refund the holiday days.

@Erik, “you should have just said no” would be something you get in writing. Next time the boss calls you tell him you’ll start as soon as the money is in your bank account.

The answer to OP's question is at the end of my answer/rant.
At my company, when a primary dev (Senior Developer on a Generaly Available Project) goes on vacation, no product changes for at minimum 2 weeks prior. Damn sure nothing during.
WTF with "Crunch Time" and other stupid behavior that is common in software. But taking it further by asking people to work during vacation? How freaking stupid?
Ok - we are not perfect at my company. We have asked people on vacation a couple of times over the years where to look for a problem in a serious down situation, but not to fix it. AND WE DID A POST MORTUM WHEN THEY GOT BACK TO THE OFFICE.
GOOD LUCK is not GOOD PLANNING. Intentional touching code like that is just crazy.
OP's Manager is worse that @john R. Strohm thinks. The manager isn't just an ass. He is a self defeating moron of the highest order.
I usually discuss career growth. If your company puts up with this, then is there any career growth available there? RUN FAST! That is not something that I as a random internet person will usually say.
UPDATE to answer: The point isn't the manager being an idiot or how the OP should react to the manager. The point is a company that doesn't understand the basics of being a business. Some of the simplest of these are to remove as much risk and uncertainty as possible while exceeding.
This company's management team seems to promote the same twisted logic as chernobyl's did. "F*** with it and see what happens". We know how well that worked out at chernobyl. That is why I am saying that the company is the problem. The OP has said that this has happened in the past. It isn't a one-off whoops.
There is no good long-term resolution for the OP at this company IMHO. Short-term fixes like not answering the phone on vacation are a waste of effort and will only cause more grief.


Should I just let him crash and burn, if he gets himself into trouble?

Yes, or at the very least get it formalised what recompense you will get for debugging all night, and if it's worth it, then debug. Otherwise I'd tell him it will have to wait for a couple more days until I can handle it.
Then leave it to him whether to escalate to someone who will make it worth my while, or fix his own crap by reverting from a backup or something.... not my problem.

What would he do if you were in the hospital, unable to pull his chestnuts out of the fire, instead of just on PTO?
Under those circumstances, he would be destined to crash and burn, and there would be nothing whatsoever you could do to save his project.
Your product manager is an ass. Worse, your people manager is facilitating him.
Get out of there. ASAP.
AT THE VERY LEAST, go up rhe food chain, at least one layer above your people manager AND your product manager, and brief them on the situation.
